# SQL merge results of different rows, combined by a case

Tags: mysql, select, sum

i have the folowing table:

```
   type    | amount   
    pine    | 10
    cypress | 40
    gold    | 30
    sylver  | 25
```

I would like to classify, merge and sum within a case:

```
SELECT CASE  WHEN (type == 'pine' OR type == 'cypress') then 'wood' end, from materials;
```

I would liek to get:

```
wood | 50
gold | 30
silver | 25
```

I though a case would merge the results but apparently isnt the case, i'm trying with a `SUM` but without success.

Comment: sorry, pressed 'enter' too quickly

Comment: And what is the result you get?

Comment: pine and cypress is literally translated into 'wood', meaning that they keep separate columns

Comment: Try to use `=` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CASE statement like that, but you'll also have to group later to get the total values. Try this:

```
SELECT 
   (CASE WHEN type = 'pine' OR type = 'cypress' THEN 'wood' ELSE type END) AS type, 
   SUM(amount) AS total
FROM myTable
GROUP BY type;
```

Your case statement doesn't have any `ELSE` to it. You should include this, because it appears that if it's not pine or cypress, then you want to select whatever type already exists for that material.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE  WHEN (type == 'pine' OR type == 'cypress') then 'wood' end as MacroType, count(*) from materials group by MacroType;
```

Comment: sorry, i just edited the initial post, thank you, the end was already there, this is a fake query, its there to show the issue, i forgot to put the 'end' initially

Comment: @JBoy I've edited the comment to add the count, below the same query for the customers (tested) SELECT CASE WHEN (Country== 'Germany' OR Country== 'UK') then 'EUROPE' END AS REGION,count(*) from Customers group by REGION;